# Stop make echoing directory it enters / exits

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a `Makefile` that traverses a list of directories, which works fine, however i want to *not* get the `Entering`/`Leaving` info message like below:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zzz/aaa/bbb/ccc'
```

The bit of code that does the traversal (where `ccc` is one of the dirs in the `SUBDIRS` list and `Makefile` is in the `bbb` dir) is here:

```
@for i in $(SUBDIRS); do \
(cd $$i; make $@); \
done
```

I am guessing something needs doing with the `(cd $$i; make $@)` part, but cannot figure out what.

Thanks

Comment: `make --no-print-directory` will do this. Oh, *please* use `${MAKE}` when calling make recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU makes decides whether to print this information according to the `MAKELEVEL`: if it is set and > 0 then it prints the info. You can unset or fake a zero `MAKELEVEL`, so GNU make thinks it is the initial invokation.

```
@for i in $(SUBDIRS); do \
    (cd $$i; unset MAKELEVEL; make $@); \
done
```

should do the trick.

On the other hand, **Recursive make considered harmful** (google it). If you can, avoid it.

**EDIT**: As bobbogo points out, there is a GNU make option `--no-print-directory`; this is much better than my hack above.

Comment: That did the trick thanks. Re recursive make, yes make is calling make, but with different makefiles in each dir i consider this style non-harmful. Totally agree if it was make calling make on the same Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using include instead of a "for" loop:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html

Comment: This can't possibly work; consider what happens if each of the makefiles has an `all:` target.